# Can I embed a Trello board into my site?

Tags: trello, embed

Simply, I would like to get a chromeless version of a Trello board and embed it directly into the 'tasks' page of my site. I'd still have my site's header and footer around it.

I guess I could just use an iFrame, but is there a more elegant solutions to this?

Also I would like to theme it to suit the rest of the site...

Anyone knows where to start with this?

Answer (score 13):

Sure you can. Check these links out:

Consider this as an example card:

```
https://trello.com/c/NIRpzVDM
```

You can link to a card as a photo using the following:

```
<img src="https://trello.com/c/NIRpzVDM.png" />
```

[image]

You could embed an iframe as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://trello.com/c/NIRpzVDM.html"></iframe>
```

You can also do a javascript that writes the card into your page:

```
<script src="https://trello.com/c/NIRpzVDM.js"></script>
```

which writes out some html using `document.write("<html content>")`

Another way is to request a card's JSON

```
https://trello.com/c/NIRpzVDM.json
```

All of these are available using a board as well...

```
https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ.png
https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ.html
https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ.js
https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ.json
```

Comment: Can anyone verify if this still works? initial attempts in Chrome gave me `GET https://trello.com/c/somecardid.png 410 (Gone)` and 
 `Refused to display 'https://trello.com/c/somecard' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.` in my console

Comment: This still works however you **must** use `.html` at the end of your board. This may change shortly, maybe, since I've just reported a vulnerability through this iframe feature so YMMV.

Comment: Isn't it strange that the trello app supports this feature but there's no documentation about it?

Comment: Is the `.png` one working for anyone? Can't get an image in Safari or Chrome...

Comment: This seems to have stopped working. The .png returns "Gone". The https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ.html shortcut returns some weird symbols. All others are denied due to X-Frame-Options DENY.

Comment: I'm still able to use `.js` and `.html` but the board must be marked as public.

Comment: @ondervloei maybe because your board is private

Answer (score 6):

Other than using an iframe, Trello has a REST public API that you can tap into for your site. You can theme it to match your site and have more control than simply a window into another site. You can find more information on programmableweb here: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/trello

Comment: I believe this'll work, but I wish Trello lets us copy&paste some js code to embed cards/lists/boards. I'm thinking of showing for (http://liveditor.com/text-editor) the bugfixes and feature implementation implementation which is managed in Trello.

Comment: Trello has a feature request board that you can post your comments to and users can vote for it to be implemented. Here's the link: https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ/trello-development